# Remove old opencv and install new one from build

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu

I built the last opencv version and I included the option to have a python version. I can find the file .so for python inside the build folder, but I don't know where to copy it. After long time trying it, I thought there could be some conflict with older versions, so I thought in doing a sudo apt-get remove python3-opencv. I also tried from pip3, but if I enter into python3, I can do an import cv2. That's why, I thought in doing a sudo apt-get remove python3. I'll never do it again. After reinstalling what I unninstalled from terminal, I got ubuntu back again. But still, I can detect opencv from python3. Does anyone have a good guide how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pip3 uninstall opencv-python` to remove the old version, and then use `pip3 install opencv-python` or `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`.

When your are finished run this code to see the current verion:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

Comment: So I'm not sure why, but still, I could do an import cv2 without errors after what you said, but once I checked the version was giving an error, so cv2 was unninstalled. Later I followed this guide: (I was building opencv for specific libraries) https://cv-tricks.com/installation/opencv-4-1-ubuntu18-04/ You may also activate the options with cmake-gui as is says here: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html but follow the extra steps of the first one!